# Logic - Propositional calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I don't understand how to show the following:
(!Q -> P) ∧ !P -> Q

I understand the answer is true as I did it with a truth table but how can I prove this using propositional logic?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! In order to best help with your question, we need to know where you're getting stuck. Do you know how to prove things in propositional logic at all? If so, what have you tried here, and why doesn't it work?

Comment: "(!Q -> P) and !P -> Q": what does this mean? Does this mean that "(!Q -> P)" is equivalent with "!P -> Q"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show that 
$$!Q \rightarrow P \ \equiv \ !P \ \rightarrow Q$$
then use the following argumentation:

In general $A\rightarrow B$ can be expressed as $!A\lor B$. Accordingly
$$!Q \rightarrow P \equiv \ !!Q\lor P\ \equiv Q\lor P$$
and
$$!P \rightarrow Q \equiv \ !!P\lor Q \ \equiv P \lor Q=Q\lor P.$$

**EDITED**

If you meant

$$[(!Q\rightarrow P)\land !P]\rightarrow Q \tag 1$$

then use again that in general $A\rightarrow B$ can be expressed as $!A\lor B$.

Regarding $(1)$

$$(!Q\rightarrow P)\land !P \equiv !!Q\lor P\land !P\equiv Q\lor P\land !P\equiv Q.$$

Comment: Sorry, I meant (!Q -> P) ∧ !P -> Q

Comment: So, you meant the $[(!Q\rightarrow P)\land !P]\rightarrow Q$ ?

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly.